# Is it possible for a function to revert if called by staticcall, and not revert if called with a state changing call?

Tags: solidity, evm

I am trying to figure out if it is possible to write a function in either Solidity or Yul, or some combination thereof, which is capable of detecting when it is being called with `staticcall` and reverting in this case?

I tried a few different things, but have not exactly figured it out yet. This is some code I have been experimenting with:

```
function changeState(uint256 _value) external returns(bool success, string memory reason) {
    require(_value != originalValue, "Choose any other number");
    oldValue = originalValue;
    originalValue = _value;
    if (oldValue != originalValue) {
        success = true;
        reason = 'OK';
        emit CallSuccess(reason);
    } else {
        
        revert CallFailedError(reason, msg.sender, tx.origin);
       
    }

}

function wrapChangeState(uint _value) public returns(bool success, bytes memory ret) {
    // require(msg.sender == tx.origin, "Sender!Origin");
    require(_value != originalValue, "Choose any other number");
    uint currentValue = originalValue;
    bytes memory data = abi.encodeWithSelector(CHANGE_SEL, _value);
    (success, ret) = address(this).call{value: 0}(data);
    require(success, "Call Failed!");
    require(currentValue != originalValue, "State did not change!");
    success = true;
}

function wrapChangeStateView(uint _value) public view returns(bool success) {
    bytes memory returnData;
    (success, returnData) = address(this).staticcall(abi.encodeWithSelector(WRAP_CHANGE_SEL, _value));
    if (! success) {
        string memory _reason = _getRevertReason(returnData);
        revert CallFailedError(_reason, msg.sender, tx.origin);

    }
}
```

If I call `wrapChangeStateView`, it will indeed revert. But then if `wrapChangeState` with `contract.functions.wrapChangeState(12121212).call()`, it does not revert.

I also tried a few tricks like checking if `msg.sender` and `tx.origin` are address(0) and reverting if so, and that works in *some cases*, but if I specify `from` like `call({'from': '0x8EC0E43756734cAc74D4f2f307743f1B8473554B'})`, that check can easily be defeated.

I tried this, which is something that ChatGPT generated, but none of these methods worked at all:

```
 function setStateVariable(uint256 newValue) public {
    uint256 initialGas = gasleft();

    // Try to change state
    stateVariable = newValue * 2;

    uint256 finalGas = gasleft();
    uint256 gasConsumed = initialGas - finalGas;

    // Mimic a timestamp change
    fakeTimestamp = block.timestamp;

    // Check if state changes were effective
    if (stateVariable != newValue * 2 || fakeTimestamp != block.timestamp) {
        revert("Possible staticcall detected");
    }

    // Use gas consumption to further infer the type of call
    if (gasConsumed == 0) {
        revert("Possible staticcall detected");
    }

    stateVariable = newValue;
} function setStateVariable(uint256 newValue) public {
    uint256 initialGas = gasleft();

    // Try to change state
    stateVariable = newValue * 2;

    uint256 finalGas = gasleft();
    uint256 gasConsumed = initialGas - finalGas;

    // Mimic a timestamp change
    fakeTimestamp = block.timestamp;

    // Check if state changes were effective
    if (stateVariable != newValue * 2 || fakeTimestamp != block.timestamp) {
        revert("Possible staticcall detected");
    }

    // Use gas consumption to further infer the type of call
    if (gasConsumed == 0) {
        revert("Possible staticcall detected");
    }

    stateVariable = newValue;
}
```

So, is it possible? Any ideas?

Comment: Regarding the question of reverting when called with staticcall, the EVM will revert if you do any state changing operation on a function called with staticcall. So, that can help you if you are doing staticcall or not. more info here: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.21/contracts.html#view-functions

Comment: Right but you call a state changing function with web3.eth.call(), or estimate_gas the EVM will still return a result. That is, you can still call a state changing method as a read only call, and it will not revert even if that function is trying to change state ... I am looking for a way to make those calls revert.